# Is my basis for $U=\{p \in \mathcal P_4(\mathbb R) \mid p(6)=0\}$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$\mathcal P_4(\mathbb R)$ is the set of polynomials with degree at most $4$ with real coefficients.

$U=\{p \in \mathcal P_4(\mathbb R) \mid p(6)=0\}$.

Would $\langle(x-6),(x-6)^2, (x-6)^3, (x-6)^4\rangle$ form a basis?

Suppose $a(x-6)+b(x-6)^2+c(x-6)^3+d(x-6)^4=0$. Then we know $a=b=c=d=0$ since the RHS has no $x, x^2, x^3, x^4$ terms. So the set of vectors is linearly independent.

Also, since $\dim U < 5$, we cannot extend a basis of $U$ beyond length $4$. Hence $\dim U=4$.

So, $\langle(x-6),(x-6)^2, (x-6)^3, (x-6)^4\rangle$ is a basis of $U$.

Comment: Well done. I would say that $d=0$ because the RHS has no $x^4$ term. It follows then that $c=0$, $\dots$. Maybe one should point out the obvious, that our proposed basis elements are in $U$.

Comment: If you are required to show this is a basis, then you may also want to elaborate on why $\dim U < 5$. It is, but it is not *immediately* obvious that it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is nearly perfect. Note, however, that it hinges on the two facts:

1. $U$ is a subspace of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$
2. $\dim U<5$

If we accept these facts, then your proof is complete. If not, then we should prove that these two facts are indeed true.

To prove that $U$ is a subspace of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$ we can use the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test). First, note that $U\neq\varnothing$ since $0\in U$. Then, let $u,v\in U$ and let $\lambda \in\Bbb R$. It follows that
$$
(u+\lambda v)(6)=u(6)+\lambda v(6)=0+\lambda0=0+0=0
$$
so $u+\lambda v\in U$. This proves that $U$ is a subspace of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$.

To prove that $\dim U<5$, simply note that the polynomial $f(x)=1$ is an element of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$ that is not in $U$. Hence $U$ is a *proper* subspace of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$. In particular, [the dimension of $U$ is strictly less than the dimension of $\cal P_4(\Bbb R)$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Proper_Subspace_Less_Than_its_Superspace). That is,
$$
\dim U<\dim\cal P_4(\Bbb R)=5
$$
as desired.